# CircleCI Throwing Configuration Error On Variable Expansion With `[\/]` In The Pattern

Tags: yaml, circleci

## Description

I'm hitting a validation error in CircleCI

```
alexlordthorsen@Alexs-MBP ~/git/data/data-platform [255] :( % circleci config validate
Error: Unable to parse YAML
while scanning a double-quoted scalar
 in 'string', line 145, column 20:
              default: "${CIRCLE_BRANCH//[\/-]/_}"
                       ^
found unknown escape character /(47)
 in 'string', line 145, column 40:
     ...    default: "${CIRCLE_BRANCH//[\/-]/_}"
```

with this command definition

```
    set-build-variables:
      parameters:
        mwaa_environment:
          type: string
          description: The MWAA environment that we want to modify with this jobs package build information.
          default: "${MWAA_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}"
        git_branch:
          type: string
          # python and s3 both change / and - to _
          default: ${CIRCLE_BRANCH//[\/-]/_}
        build_number:
          type: string
          default: "${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}"
```

on a variable expansion that's working in my local shell (both bash and zsh)

```
alexlordthorsen@Alexs-MBP ~/git/data/data-platform/tests/integration :)% echo "${CIRCLE_BRANCH//[\/-]/_}"
env_dev_qa
```

Why is circleCI throwing this error?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved by dropping the double quotes around the expansion.

```
default: "${CIRCLE_BRANCH//[\/-]/_}"
```

to

```
default: ${CIRCLE_BRANCH//[\/-]/_}
```